# Condition for outward pointing normal vector

Tags: vector-analysis, divergence-theorem

I'm now trying to prove Gauss' divergence theorem with a [lecture note](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Ebdriver/231-02-03/Lecture_Notes/PDE-Anal-Book/analpde1.pdf) by Professor B.K. Driver.
But I'm facing a problem with outward pointing condition on page 530.

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a manifold with boundary, which means,
for each point $x_0 \in \Omega \setminus \Omega^{\circ}$, there exist $\varepsilon > 0$, an open set $D \subset \mathbb R^n$ containing $0$ and a diffeomorphism $\psi: D \to B_{\varepsilon}(p)$ such that

$$\psi( D \cap \{ y_n \geq 0 \} ) = \Omega \cap B_{\varepsilon}(x_0).$$

(For this definition, see page 528.)

Then, a vector $n(x_0) \in \mathbb R^n$ is said to be outward pointing if

$$\psi'(0) e_n \cdot n(x_0) < 0$$

equivalently, letting $\phi = \psi^{-1}$,

$$\phi'(x_0) n(x_0) \cdot e_n < 0.$$

The latter condition is natural since the condition means
$\phi'(x_0) n(x_0)$ is a vector pointing $\{ y_n \geq 0 \}$ which corresponds to the outside of the $\Omega$.

But, the former condition is mysterious for me.
Can anyone prove equivalency?